# How to convert USD to NIS in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I need a function that converts American Dollars to New Israeli Shekels in a Google Spreadsheet. Is there such a function, or a viable workaround?

Comment: First result on Google with following keywords [google currency spreadsheet](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/3xEAsAIN21o)

Comment: I found that as well, but it doesn't seem to work for NIS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `NIS (New Israeli Shekel)` is not an international accepted currency, but the `ILS (Israeli new shekel)` is. Therefore you need to use the following formula

### Formula

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDILS")
```

### Screenshot

[image]
[image]

### References

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_new_shekel

Comment: And to save space, you can do =GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDILS") * 792 (with 792 being the current USD value as an example)

Answer (score 0):

to get by date

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDILS","price", date(2017,11,15))
```